# How to create a list of checkboxes from a JavaScript query for Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I am building a website where for Medical Professionals where the logged in user can see a list of their patients by querying from Firebase. I have managed to get retrieve the data from Firebase and display in in a div in my HTML page, but only as a bullet list. How can I convert the bullet list to a list of checkboxes?

HTML:

```
<h2>Welcome, </h2>
<h3>Please find your patients listed below</h3>

    <div class="container">
            <ul class="patientsList" id="patients-list">
            </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <button class="RiskProfileBtn">View Patients Risk Profile</button><br>
    <button id="RiskReportBtn">Run Risk Report for Patient</button><br><br>
```

JavaScript:

```
const patientsList = document.querySelector('#patients-list');

function renderPatientList(doc) {
let li = document.createElement('li');
let name = document.createElement('span');
let Email = document.createElement('span');
let Address = document.createElement('span');
let GPID = document.createElement('span');
let InsuranceCompany = document.createElement('span');

li.setAttribute = ('data-id', doc.id);

name.textContent = doc.data().name;
Email.textContent = doc.data().email;
Address.textContent = doc.data().Address;
GPID.textContent = doc.data().GPID;
InsuranceCompany.textContent = doc.data().InsuranceCompany;

li.appendChild(name);
li.appendChild(Email);
li.appendChild(Address);
li.appendChild(GPID);
li.appendChild(InsuranceCompany);

patientsList.appendChild(li);
```

}

[image: Screenshot of the Div]

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the list item image with a live checkbox? Not possible, but you can create the input element and prefix the text content of the `li` with that input. Use some CSS to style the `li`s and inputs to look like a list item images.

Answer (score 2):

for each **patient**, create a `<li>` and **append inside it** an `<input>` element using `appendChild()` function and add `type='checkbox'` **attribute** to the `<input>` element.

Comment: I do not think this will work as the list is created dynamically

Comment: @GearoidSheehan Notice, that you can add these steps to the code for the dynamic creation ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
        const patientsList = document.querySelector('#patients-list');

        let li = document.createElement('li');
        let name = document.createElement('span');
        let Email = document.createElement('span');
        //Repeat above two   lines for email and address


        li.setAttribute = ('data-id', 'doc.id 123');

        name.textContent = 'John'; //E.g doc.data().name === Johm
        Email.textContent = ' john@example.com'; //E.g doc.data().email === 'john@example.com';

        li.appendChild(name);
        li.appendChild(Email);

        patientsList.appendChild(li);

        //Removing default list item styling
        $("#patients-list li").css("list-style", "none")

        // Get all the list items inside 'patientsList' unordered list along with their text value inside span tag
        $('#patients-list li').each(function () {
            let li_item_value = $(this).text()
            $("li").prepend(`<input type='checkbox' value='${li_item_value}'/> `) //Set value="Patient Firebase Reference ID" to identify selected patient'
        });


        //handling Submit button action
        $('#submit_btn').click(function () {
            var selected = [];
            $('#patients-list input:checked').each(function () {
                selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });

            //Displaying Selected Checkboxes along with value
            if (selected.length > 0) {
                //Do Action
                console.log("Selected Patient List: ", selected)
            } else {
                alert("Please Select Atleast One Patient from the list")
            }

        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>Welcome, </h2>
    <h3>Please find your patients listed below</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="patientsList" id="patients-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```